# Update Field With Another Field Value Dynamically in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have two models ModelA and ModelB

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    amount_per_product=models.PositiveIntegerField(default='', help_text="e.g 10000")

class ModelB(models.Model):
    no_of_product_needed=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    amount_to_pay=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    modela=models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

Now, whenever a user put a number e.g `2` in the `no_of_product_needed` field, Django should show the total amount the user will pay in the `amount_to_pay` field before saving. So the user can see the total amount and if he/she wants to buy, the user will click buy and Django will save the total amount in the `amount_to_pay` field.

I wrote a pre_save hook but it's not working. Whenever I insert a number in the `no_of_product_needed` field, it won't show the total amount in the `amount_to_pay` field.

The Hook

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    no_of_product_needed=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    amount_to_pay=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    modela=models.ForeignKey(ModelA)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelB, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pre_save.connect(self.before_buying, sender=ModelB)


    def before_buying(self, sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        initial= self.modela.amount_per_product
        amt_needed= self.no_of_product_needed
        final_amt=int(initial) * int(amt_needed)
        self.amount_to_pay= self.final_amt
```

What am I missing? Could this be done in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Django should show the total amount the user will pay in the amount_to_pay field before saving"

This not the goal of django to update client view. You pre_save method don't update template.

If you want inform user about the amount_to_pay, you need to do it with Javascript, on client side.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I also think so. I'm still searching for a js function I can use to do that. Any recommendation?

Comment: You can use jquery. You create a listener on change event, on your input no of product. And in function callback, update your value of amount_to_pay. (A readonly input).